# Table always goes to bottom of document?

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix table position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9485/how-to-fix-table-position)

I'm defining a table in my document like so...

```
\begin{table}
 \caption{my table}
 \centering

  \begin{tabular}{c llll c c c c}
  \hline         
   Stuff & \multicolumn {1}{ c }{  } & more Stuff
  \end{tabular}
  \label{table:nonlin} 
\end{table}
```

The table itself is pretty big, takes up almost the entire page. I'm creating it between two blocks of text however when compiled into a pdf it appears to just "float" to the bottom of the document. Why is this happening? How do I correct it?

Answer (score 24):

The environment `table` is supposed to float so it's working as intended. Actually it's often a good practice to let LaTeX place the floats.

To control the placement of the table you can provide the environment with options. For example you can use the option `htbp` as in

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
...
\end{table}
```

See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_table_environment_-_captioning_etc for details.

Comment: `[htp]` or `[htbp]`, not `[h]` only.

Comment: @egreg Oops! Fixed.

Comment: Actually LaTeX always adds `tp` (but not `b`); adding the options avoids the warning.

Comment: Adding ! in front of the h (ie [!htp]) can try and overule LaTeX as  to where the best placement for the table is.

Comment: @drezha: The [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) provides the `H` specifier for overriding float placement to `H`ere.

Comment: As @egreg said, `[htp]` works perfectly if your tables must be at the beginning of a page (esp. of a journal paper).

Comment: Define 'often a good practice', please. Why? To be honest, I often get the idea latex tries to avoid overfulls, underfulls and overflows, but does not consider that specific placement might appear better of be clearer. In particular when LaTeX throws a float all the way to the bottom of a document on separate page, which is ugly and confusing when the table was referenced to 5 pages ago.

Comment: For example: https://pastebin.com/ZbtHCv41