# inserting sentences between two graphs

Tags: floats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

Hello I am trying to write between two figures, but when I am entering a text between them in the code,everything goes on the top of the two figures,why?

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\setlength\fboxsep{5.5pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{0.5pt}
\includegraphics[width=80mm,height=70mm]{ZeroReserveGraph_France-Sweden_0,75.jpg}
\end{center}
\caption{Graph for France and Sweden with ratio (0.75).}
\label{zerocapitalFranceSweeden_0,75}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\setlength\fboxsep{5.5pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{0.5pt}
\includegraphics[width=80mm,height=70mm]{ZeroReserveGraph_France-Sweden_0,75.jpg}
\end{center}
\caption{Graph for France and Sweden with ratio (0.75).}
\label{zerocapitalFranceSweeden_0,75}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks..

Comment: The `figure` environment is an example of a `float`. Have a look at the answer to [how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020). On another note, have a look at [should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables) :)

Comment: Other relevant questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9485/how-to-fix-table-position

Comment: Do you want to *always* have a sentence between the two figures?

Comment: Do you want these three elements (the two figures and the text) to be always on a same page or are page breaks allowed between them?