# Specific page at number

Tags: page-numbering

I want to put a specific page (with pictures) at a special page number. Does somoene know how to dot that ?

Exemple :
page 1 - 20 : normal text 
page 21 : special page width a picture 
page 21 - end : end of the text

Thanks for you help !
Kind regards,

Comment: Does the special page contain *only* the special picture, or is there also normal flowing text on the page, too?

Comment: Only a picture !

Comment: Could this question/answer help?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95022/forcing-a-table-or-image-on-a-specified-page?  In order to make it on a page by itself, change `[t]` to `[p]` in `\checkpage` definition, and define the `\figpage` to be one page before the image is to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extra wide figure made to appear on page 10, based on answer at [Forcing a table or image on a specified page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95022/forcing-a-table-or-image-on-a-specified-page).  However, here, `[p]` option used for figure, `\everypar` is also used.

Extra wideness created with a `\makebox[\textwidth]{<figure content>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen,lipsum}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\holdFigures
\bxfigure{Here is my caption}
  {\makebox[\textwidth]{\fbox{\rule{7in}{5in}}}}
\newcommand\checkpage{\ifthenelse{\equal{\csname %
  figpage\roman{figure}\endcsname}{\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax}}%
  {\nextFigure[p]}{}}
\def\figpage{10}
\begin{document}
\everypar{\checkpage}
\lipsum[1-70]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer ! It looks good ! But I'm trying to put a includegraphics and it doesn't work anymore...

```
\bxfigure{Here is my caption}
  {\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{pic.png}}

\newcommand\checkpage{\ifthenelse{\equal{\csname %
  figpage\roman{figure}\endcsname}{\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax}}%
  {\nextFigure[p]}{}}
\def\figpage{10}
```

Comment: This should have been an edit to your original question (or, if small enough, a comment to my answer).  It is not an answer in itself.  However, I found that if the image is small enough that LaTeX thinks it can fit two of them on a single page, it holds back the `[p]` pictures in an attempt to do so.  Just as an experiment, increase the scale of the `\includegraphics`.  Alternately, add a  tall rule,`\rule{0pt}{5in}` for example, immediately prior to the `\includegraphics` (but as part of the 2nd `\bxfigure` argument).  If this fixes the problem, then this is the issue.