# table using \input{mytable.tex}

Tags: tables, input

I have the following `\input{mytable.tex}` in my thesis document.

```
%% LaTeX2e file `mytable.tex'
%% generated by the `filecontents' environment
%% from source `thesiss' on 2016/10/11.
%%
\begin{table}
\centering
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{2.0}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 $\mu \in X$& Condition applied on $\delta_{\mu}$  & Implication upon lifting \\ \hline
$-4$ & $\bigg(\dfrac{13\cdot1789}{q}=-1\bigg)$  & $n \not\equiv k-4 \pmod{2k}$  \\ \hline
$-3$ & $\bigg(\dfrac{5\cdot29}{q}=-1\bigg)$  & $n \not\equiv k-3 \pmod{2k}$  \\ \hline
 $-2$ & - & - \\ \hline
$-1$ & $\bigg(\dfrac{5\cdot29}{q}=-1\bigg)$  & $n \not\equiv k-1 \pmod{2k}$  \\ \hline
$0$ & $\bigg(\dfrac{2}{q}=-1\bigg)$  & $n \not\equiv k \pmod{2k}$  \\ \hline
$3$ & $\bigg(\dfrac{5333\cdot97324757}{q}=-1\bigg)$  & $n \not\equiv k+3 \pmod{2k}$  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\caption{Conditions following from pushing up modulus.\label{condition}}
\end{table}
```

and in my thesis :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amssymb,bm}
\begin{document}
\noindent Thus, the four conditions in the table above given by $\bigg(\dfrac{\delta_\mu}{q}\bigg)=-1$, with $\delta_\mu=\{2, 5 \cdot 29, 13 \cdot 1789, 5333 \cdot 97324757\}$  implies that $n \not\equiv k+\mu \pmod{2k}$. \qed

\input{mytable.tex} \qed
\end{document}
```

And this table appears not at the right position where I have placed it in my thesis. Is there anything that can fix it. For example, maybe I can use something like `\begin{XXX}[htpb!]`

Comment: Could we have a full compilable example?

Comment: Sorry about this.. I will include my MWE.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9485/how-to-fix-table-position and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: the fact that it is `\input` makes no difference. You have put it in a `table` environment, the only reason for that environment is to allow latex to move the table.

Comment: Thank you. I initially thought changes should be done to \input for example \input{mytable.tex}[htpb!].