# Force texts to appear at the end of the sections

Tags: tables, spacing

I have a small section with 10 lines and 3 big tables in that sections. So it looks like this

```
\section{example}

line. line. line. line. line.
table1, table2, table3
line. line. line. line. line.
```

So what I am trying to do is that, show first 5 lines at the beginning of the section, then all three tables and then rest of the 5 lines. But latex shows all the 10 lines at first and then it shows all the tables. How can I force few texts to appear at the end of the section.

Comment: Take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9486/120578 LaTeX use its own way to decide where to place the tables.. This is  for all floating environments and sometimes can be fixed using the linked answer. Other times you can just use a tabular environment without a table environment (and may be a custom caption or a usage of `caption` package)

Comment: basically it sounds like you want `\clearpage` after `table3`