# Force figure to be on the first page of chapter even if too big

Tags: floats, positioning, chapters, figure-placement

Given the minimal working example below: How would I force the figure to be on the same page as the chapter headline "The End", *without* making it smaller?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The Start}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter*{The End}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=8cm]{A}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{figure}[t!]` will put it above **The End.** `\begin{figure}[h!]` will put it below.  (Tested using `example-image`.)

Comment: But if you are using a chapter with only a chapter title and one or more figures, you maybe even [don't want them to float](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9485/277964).

Comment: @JohnKormylo this worked already, thanks!